# Turn off marker movement to the center of map Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I am using a customize InfoWindow in Google Map using InfoWindowAdapter. Every time I click on a marker, it moves to the center of the mobile screen and open the info window. I was wondering if it is possible to stop the marker movement from the current location to the center. I am using the following code:

```
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new UserInfoWindowAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {      
        //other Code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first the code:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    Marker mLastMarker;
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        if (marker.equals(mLastMarker)) {
            // Same marker clicked twice - hide InfoWindow
            mLastMarker = null;
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
        } else {
            mLastMarker = marker;
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Secondly the functionality that the above code provides:

- Overrides the default OnMarkerClick functionality (`return true;`)
- Imitates `isInfoWindowShown` functionality as there is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5408) to that method
- With the help of the previous point, toggles the InfoWindow visibility

Good luck!